# time series unsupervised learning project for a company product/customer database

Tags: python

I want to extract new subscribers from a timeseries for unsupervised learning project for each partition. it has the entry column,pk_ batch_partition and pk_cid a bunch of product columns as booleans and customer segments ...
columns:    pk_cid  short_term_deposit  loans   mortgage    funds   securities  long_term_deposit   em_account_pp   credit_card payroll ... entry_date  entry_channel   active_customer segment country_id  region_code gender  age deceased    salary

rows:pk_partition 2018-01-28    1000028 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.0 ... 2017-01-03  KHC True    02 - PARTICULARES   ES  28.0    H   43  0   133378.89
I define new subscriber as subscriber whose entry date is in the range of it's index (pk_partition) and the previous pk_partition. I added a column called prev_partition and code the condition that if entry date is between its index and the pre_partition make new_subscriber column 1 else keep 0. here is the code:# Assuming 'merged_all_three' is your DataFrame with datetime index 'pk_partition' and 'entry_date' column
`first_partition = pd.to_datetime('2017-12-29')

```
 # Shift index to the previous month and add one day to get the previous partition date with     the same day + 1
merged_all_three['prev_partition'] = merged_all_three.index.to_period('M').to_timestamp('M') -        pd.DateOffset(days=2)-pd.DateOffset(months=1)
merged_all_three['new_subscriber'] = 0 
# Update prev_partition for '2018-02-28' and '2019-02-28'

merged_all_three.loc[merged_all_three['prev_partition'] == pd.Timestamp('2018-02-28'),     'prev_partition'] = pd.Timestamp('2018-03-01')
merged_all_three.loc[merged_all_three['prev_partition'] == pd.Timestamp('2019-02-28'),     'prev_partition'] = pd.Timestamp('2019-03-01')
# Create a mask for rows where entry_date is between prev_partition and index
for index, row in merged_all_three.iterrows():
# Check if the condition is met for the current row
if (row['prev_partition'] <= row['entry_date']) and (row['entry_date'] <= index):
    # Set 'new_subscriber' to 1 for the current row
    merged_all_three.at[index, 'new_subscriber'] = 1
else:
    # Set 'new subscriber' to 0 for the current row
    merged_all_three.at[index, 'new subscriber'] = 0`
```

### this is the error:

`Keyboard Interrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[419], line 19
16     merged_all_three.at[index, 'new_subscriber'] = 1
17 else:
18     # Set 'new_subscriber' to 0 for the current row
---> 19     merged_all_three.at[index, 'new_subscriber'] = 0

```
File c:\Users\donna\anaconda3\envs\Capstone_Project\Lib\site-    packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:2496, in _AtIndexer.__setitem__(self, key, value)
```

2493     if not isinstance(key, tuple) or not all(is_scalar(x) for x in key):
2494         raise ValueError("Invalid call for scalar access (setting)!")
-> 2496     self.obj.loc[key] = value
2497     return
2499 return super().**setitem**(key, value)

```
File c:\Users\donna\anaconda3\envs\Capstone_Project\Lib\site-    packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:885, in _LocationIndexer.__setitem__(self, key, value)
882 self._has_valid_setitem_indexer(key)
884 iloc = self if self.name == "iloc" else self.obj.iloc
```

--> 885 iloc._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value, self.name)

File c:\Users\donna\anaconda3\envs\Capstone_Project\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1893, in _iLocIndexer._setitem_with_indexer(self, indexer, value, name)
1890 # align and set the values
1891 if take_split_path:
1892     # We have to operate column-wise
-> 1893     self._setitem_with_indexer_split_path(indexer, value, name)
...
--> 354         applied = getattr(b, f)(**Kwags)
355     result blocks = extend blocks(applied, result blocks)
357 out = type(self).from blocks(result_blocks, self. Axes) `
can anyone help me?  the loop keeping running forever.

I tried to convert date to datetime, then printed the iterations and found that entry_date was changed and corrected it. Then keep just tweaking the whole concept in other styles like masking which ended up making all rows as new subscribers.